# Comparing two lines from two text files according to a single part of the text file

Tags: python, text

I have two text files and I want to write out two new text files according to whether there is a common section to each line in the two original text files.

The format of the text files is as follows:

```
commontextinallcases   uniquetext2   potentiallycommontext    uniquetext4
```

There are more than 4 columns but you get the idea. I want to check the 'potentiallycommontext' part in each text file and if they are the same write out the whole line of each text file to a new text file for each with its own unique text still in place.

Spliting it is fairly easy just using the .split() command when reading it in. I have found the following code:

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1:
with open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

But I am not sure this would work for my case where I need to split the lines. Is there a way to do this I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: You can split a string over different words, and check the third entry of the splitted result.

Answer (score 0):

There might be shorter solutions but this should work

```
PCT_IDX = _  # find which index of line.split() corresponds to potentiallycommontext

def lines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            yield line

lines_1 = lines('some_file_1.txt')
lines_2 = lines('some_file_2.txt')
with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for (line_1, line_2) in zip(lines_1, lines_2):
        maybe_cmn1 = line_1.split()[PCT_IDX]
        maybe_cmn2 = line_2.split()[PCT_IDX]
        if maybe_cmn1 == maybe_cmn2:
            file_out.write(line_1)
            file_out.write(line_2)
```

Comment: this answer assumes you're using python3. tuple unpacking magic is not available in py2.7 and you'd need to specify all columns/use indexing

Comment: Sorry I should specify I am doing this in 2.7 as the linux workstation I use only has 2.7.

Comment: i've updated the answer for 2.7  Make sure you first run something like:
`with open(file_input_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split())`
to find which index you need in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this set-approach is suitable for your case.
I'd try like

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2, open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        if line1.split()[2] == line2.split()[2]:
            file_out.write(line1)
            file_out.write(line2)
```

Comment: There is an index error out of range if I do this method. If I print the split lines they are indeed split up but trying to index any part of it gives an index out fo range error. Not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a `print(len(line1.split()), len(line2.split()))` before the conditional and check wether it falls below 3 right before the error occurs. Hard to say sth without the data in use.